# Verify multiple ranges in webtable using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web table to verify Values:

ID   Date           %   Month 
1     30-10-2017
  75
  JAN


2
  18-10-2017
  80
  FEB


3
  01-11-2017
  60
  MAR

4
  22-10-2017
  67
  APR

I want to verify
 
1. Date values are within range '15-10-2107' to '15-11-2017'
2. % Range between 50-90
3. Month Range between Jan - May

I am using Selenium C# for verification. What will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use xpath to narrow the dataset firstly (so that you no need to loop all rows of table)

   ```
   string xpath = '//table//td[3][number(text())>=50 and number(text())<=90]';
   first_filter_rows = driver.FindElements(By.xpath(xpath));
   ```
2. use month range do the 2rd filter on the first_filter_rows

   ```
   Regex reg = new Regex("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May");
   ArrayList second_filter_rows = new ArrayLis();
   foreach(row in first_filter_rows) {
   string month = row.FindElement(By.xpaht('./td[4]')).text;
   if(reg.IsMatch(month)) {
    second_filter_rows.add(row);
   }
   }
   ```
3. use date range do the 3rd filter on the second_filter_rows

   ```
   var start = DateTime.ParseExact("15-10-2017", "dd-mm-yyyy",
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

       var end = DateTime.ParseExact("15-11-2017", "dd-mm-yyyy", 
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       ArrayList third_filter_rows = new ArrayLis();

       foreach(row in second_filter_rows) {
         string date = row.FindElement(By.xpaht('./td[2]')).text;
         var dateFromtable = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-mm-yyyy", 
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       if(dateFromtable >= start && dateFromtable < end) {
           third_filter_rows.add(row);
           // output to your report
       }
       }

       Assert(third_filter_rows.length > 0, IsTrue);
   ```

Comment: why do you use additional citation around your code blocks? Do you refer to code elsewhere?

Comment: the code block toolbar can't work as expected some times.

Answer (score 1):

To test a date falls within a specified range, you can construct a DateTime object and assert that its within a 2 set DateTime ranges:

```
var start = DateTime.ParseExact("15-10-2017", "dd-mm-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var end = DateTime.ParseExact("15-11-2017", "dd-mm-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dateFromtable = DateTime.ParseExact([DATE_FROM_TABLE], "dd-mm-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Assert.That(dateFromtable  >= start && dateFromtable < end, Is.True);
```

To test your % a simple int cast and check similar to the date assert above.

Your Month check can be done in many different ways, the simplest most straight forward i believe would be to construct a list that contains acceptable months

```
var acceptableMonths = new[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"}; //Assuming may is included in the list
Assert.That(acceptableMonths.Contains([MONTH_READ_FROM_TABLE]), Is.True)
```

Comment: Is there any other way than using Assert.That, e.g. using if else, as I need to add the results to my reports too...

Comment: The first argument in all the 'Assert.That' actually returns a bool obj. So you can do if(dateFromtable  >= start && dateFromtable < end) of if(acceptableMonths.Contains([MONTH_READ_FROM_TABLE]) and it should still work